# struts2 action mapping incorrect

Tags: java, html, jsp, model-view-controller, struts2

I have 2 actionClasses, one is called on startup. I'm trying to call an action with a button press (for now) that goes to another page and prints a message in the console saying this action was successful, but when I click on it it isn't called. Am I doing something wrong?

struts.xml

```
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="*" class="actionPackage.ActionClass1">
            <result name="homepage">/default.jsp</result>
            <result name="myNextPage">/nextPage.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

actionClass1

```
public String execute(){
    System.out.println("the web application is working properly!");
    return "homepage";
}
```

actionClass2

```
public String execute(){
    System.out.println("the button works!");
    return "myNextPage";
}
```

default.jsp

```
function strutsTestFunc(){document.getElementById("querySubmitter").submit()}
```

...

```
<form name="searchForm" method="post" action="actionPackage.ActionClass2" id="querySubmiter">
```

...

```
<input id="filterSubmit" type="submit" value="Search" onclick="strutsTestFunc()">
```

When I click the button it goes to "/actionPackage.ActionClass2" and gives me a 404 error. is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: if you are trying to define your actions as wildcard then read the following http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html or you can also visit http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/struts-2-tutorials/ to get better understanding how struts2 works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mappings are wrong. Also avoid using `*` wildcard to map all actions, bypassing in fact the framework mechanisms.

```
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="action1" class="actionPackage.ActionClass1">
            <result name="homepage">/default.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="action2" class="actionPackage.ActionClass2">
            <result name="myNextPage">/nextPage.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

in JSP, always point to the mapping of the action, not to the action class itself:

```
<form action = "action2" 
        name = "searchForm" 
      method = "post"  
          id = "querySubmiter" >
```

After it works, start using default results like SUCCESS, and submit with `<s:submit />` struts tag, that does not require javascript.